# Is there a simple way to convert a lua table to a C++ array or vector?

Tags: lua, package-managers, lua-c++-connection

I am starting to make my own package manager and am starting to develop a dependency system.
The builfiles are written in lua, they look something like this:

```lua
package = {
  name = "pfetch",
  version = "0.6.0",
  source = "https://github.com/dylanaraps/pfetch/archive/0.6.0.tar.gz",
  git = false
}

dependencies = {
   "some_dep",
   "some_dep2"
}

function install()
  quantum_install("pfetch", false)
end
```

Only problem,I have no idea how to convert

```lua
dependencies = {
   "some_dep",
   "some_dep2"
}
```

To a global c++ array: `["some_dep", "some_dep2"]`
Anything in the list that's not valid as a string should be ignored.
Any good way to do this?
Thanks in advance

**Note**: I am using the C api to interface with lua in C++. I don't know whether Lua's errors use `longjmp` or C++ exceptions.

Comment: No simple way.  1) Push each Lua string to C API stack and convert to C pointer `lua_gettable + lua_tostring`; 2) Create C array; 3) Pass C array to C function; 4) Only after C function exits you can pop all your Lua strings from C API stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Lua table to C array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662650/convert-lua-table-to-c-array)

Comment: @Nifim - When working with strings (unlike numbers), you have to think about possible "surprises" from GC.

Comment: That's a good point, i hadn't really thought about how an array of strings would make this a different beast.

Comment: What do you want to do with the array/vector? Operate on it immediately then discard it, save it to a C++ global or something, or pass it back into Lua as a userdata? Also, is your Lua compiled with C++ so that errors use exceptions instead of longjmp? And what should happen if the list has something invalid in it?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica 

1. I want the array to become a C++ global

2. No idea

3. The invalid thing would be ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the clarification in your comment, something like this will work for you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <lua5.3/lua.hpp>

std::vector<std::string> dependencies;

static int q64795651_set_dependencies(lua_State *L) {
    dependencies.clear();
    lua_settop(L, 1);
    for(lua_Integer i = 1; lua_geti(L, 1, i) != LUA_TNIL; ++i) {
        size_t len;
        const char *str = lua_tolstring(L, 2, &len);
        if(str) {
            dependencies.push_back(std::string{str, len});
        }
        lua_settop(L, 1);
    }
    return 0;
}

static int q64795651_print_dependencies(lua_State *) {
    for(const auto &dep : dependencies) {
        std::cout << dep << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

static const luaL_Reg q64795651lib[] = {
    {"set_dependencies", q64795651_set_dependencies},
    {"print_dependencies", q64795651_print_dependencies},
    {nullptr, nullptr}
};

extern "C"
int luaopen_q64795651(lua_State *L) {
    luaL_newlib(L, q64795651lib);
    return 1;
}
```

Demo:

```
$ g++ -fPIC -shared q64795651.cpp -o q64795651.so
$ lua5.3
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> q64795651 = require('q64795651')
> dependencies = {
>>    "some_dep",
>>    "some_dep2"
>> }
> q64795651.set_dependencies(dependencies)
> q64795651.print_dependencies()
some_dep
some_dep2
>
```

One important pitfall: since you're not sure if Lua is compiled to use `longjmp` or exceptions for its errors, you need to make sure that you don't have any automatic variables with destructors anywhere that a Lua error could happen. (This is already the case in the code in my answer; just make sure you don't accidentally add any such places when incorporating this into your program.)

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you clarify on what you said at the end? I'm still a c++ beginner but it's fun to take on large projects.

Comment: @ChocolateMeteor Lua can be compiled to either use `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` or C++ exceptions for its errors. [`setjmp()`/`longjmp()` do not play well in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1376085/7509065). If your Lua is compiled with `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` and you can't change it, then you need to be very careful not to accidentally allow Undefined Behavior if a Lua error happens.

Comment: Ok thanks! Also a noob question: How would I adapt your code to accept a file like [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/quantum-package-manager/repo/main/repo/neofetch/quantum.lua) (where it grabs the dependencies from the second variable) Note: I  already have made it so it can process everything but the dependency part

Comment: @ChocolateMeteor So instead of taking the table as a parameter, you want to read it from the Lua global called `dependencies`? If so, then replace the first `lua_settop(L, 1);` with `lua_settop(L, 0);
lua_getglobal(L, "dependencies");`.